# Problem with EMA using Security() in Pine Script Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I´m need to code an indicator that let me know the value of an ema from another TF (part of a bigger indicator).

This is my code to get a 9 period ema over a bbw on 15 minutes TF:

```
bbw2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", bbw(src, length, mult))
emabbw2 = ema(bbw2, 9)
```

But the value I get of emabbw2 when I am in 1M is not the same I get when I´m in 15M, so how can I code this to get the correct ema value from 15M when I´m in 1M chart?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Need to let `security()` make the calcs in its context:

```
bbw2 = bbw(src, length, mult)
emabbw2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", ema(bbw2, 9))
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work fine. But please, if possible let me understand something: You are giving to bbw2 the value of the bbw for the current TF. So when you use it to calculate emabbw2 you are using a valur from current TF and not 15. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `security()` will sort of "back up" to the logic used to calculate the variable, which can be quite involved and span multiple lines in your code. Yes, you are correct in that it takes the logic from your code that is running at the chart's resolution, but it then applies it in the HTF context you call `security()` with: `"15"` in your case, and so yields results as if your logic was run at that TF. That's the beauty of `security()`.